# Is there a more sophisticated place to enter a formula to make it easier to work?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets there is one line at the top of the screen where you can type in a formula. As a programmer, after running into a few issues, the question comes to mind, is there an expanded view that has features like:

- larger entry area like a text area with multiple lines
- syntax highlighting*
- live processing of the function as you type it so you can see if it's working
- showing errors live or when clicking a button
- intellisense or auto complete*

*It looks like the current function text input already supports this.

By **showing errors** means showing errors using visual cues or error messages:
[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. you can resize the top formula bar.

Comment: @ztiaa what?! how come no one told me this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> larger entry area like a text area with multiple lines

Use the formula editor directly in the cell. Open a cell for editing by pressing **Enter**, then type your formula. Insert line breaks by pressing **Control + Enter**. When done, press **Enter** or **Tab** to save the formula and exit editing.

You can also do the same in the formula bar. To get more vertical space, drag the bottom edge of the formula bar down with the mouse.

> syntax highlighting

This is supported.

> live processing of the function as you type it so you can see if it's working

This is supported. Select a portion of the formula you are editing to see what that part evaluates to. While you are editing a formula, you can toggle formula result previews with **F9**. See the *Use formulas* section in the [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=spreadsheets_shortcuts&answer=181110) help page.

> showing errors live or when clicking a button

What.

> intellisense or auto complete

This is supported. Press **Tab** to accept suggested completions.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details

Comment: The contributors of this Q&A site cannot implement new features in the Google Sheets formula editor. To let Google know of your request, open a spreadsheet and choose **Help > Report a Problem** or **Help > Help Sheets Improve**. If you are on a paid Google Workspace Domain, see [Contact Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).